# Adobe Flash CS5: Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Error

Tags: adobe-flash, adobe-cs5, visual-c++, runtime-error

**I installed Adobe Master Collection CS5.5 on my machine and whenever I run Flash I get this error.**

[image]

**Following is the event log:**

[image]

**I have tried:**

1. Upgrading Windows 7 to SP1
2. Deleting the Adobe directory in application data
3. Reinstalling CS5.5
4. Installing Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package x64
5. Installing all updates in "Windows Update"
6. Installing x64 versions of the following:

[image]

Comment: This is a generic crash message for Visual C++ applications, you need help from Adobe to troubleshoot the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happens to me...
I installed Cs5 about two months ago and it worked pretty well untill today, two months later.
As soon as I open the program, this message appears and the program gets closed whe I click ok.
I can still work on Cs5 but I have to ingnore the message and that window will remain open as long as I work on Cs5...

Answer (score 0):

Reboot, update Windows, reboot, update CS5, update Adobe Flash Player, reboot. (this worked for me when I had a similar problem, I don't know if the error codes are the same though)